# Still having an Unhandled Exception after editing it a bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

```
Inventory::Inventory()
{
    this->cap = 10;
    this->nrOfItems = 0;
    this->itemArr = new Item* [cap]();
}


Inventory::~Inventory()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems; i++)
    {
        delete this->itemArr[i];
    }
    delete[] this->itemArr;
}

void Inventory::expand()
{
    this->cap *= 2;

    Item **tempArr = new Item*[this->cap]();



    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems, i++;)
    {
        tempArr[i] = new Item(*this->itemArr[i]);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems, i++;)
    {
        delete this->itemArr[i];
    }
    delete[] this->itemArr;


    this->itemArr = tempArr;

    this->initialize(this->nrOfItems);
}

void Inventory::initialize(const int from)
{
    for (size_t i = from; i < cap, i++;)
    {
        this->itemArr[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

void Inventory::addItem(const Item& item)
{
    if (this->nrOfItems >= this->cap)
    {
        expand();
    }

    this->itemArr[this->nrOfItems++] = new Item(item);
}

void Inventory::removeItem(int index)
{

}
```

Above is my code from Inventory.cpp and the issue is that I keep getting an Unhandled Exception from the line that has:

```
this->itemArr[i] = nullptr;
```

I have no idea where I'm messing up in the code. Below I am posting from Inventory.h:

```
class Inventory
{
private:
    int cap;
    int nrOfItems;
    Item **itemArr;
    void expand();
    void initialize(const int from);

public:
    Inventory();
    ~Inventory();
    void addItem(const Item &item);
    void removeItem(int index);
    inline void debugPrint() const    
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->nrOfItems; i++)
        {
            std::cout << this->itemArr[i]->debugPrint() << std::endl;
        }
    }

};
```

This is where itemArr should be housed but for some reason, it is not pulling. I am new to coding so I don't know all of the tips and tricks involved with it.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but more likely this is a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: What is the value of `i` at the time of the problem? What is the size of the relevant array at that time? Similarly what about `cap` and `nrOfItems` at that moment? Is this when `initialize` is being called from `expand` or do you call it elsewhere? In fact, if it's initializing things, why aren't you calling it from the constructor after `this->itemArr = new Item* [cap]();` ?

Comment: @TheUndeadFish there is no need to call `initialize()` in the `Inventory` constructor, as the `()` after `[cap]` will directly value-initialize the array elements to `nullptr`.  In fact, the new array in `expand()` is also being value-initialized, too, making the call to `initialize()` redundant.

Comment: Prefer to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>` over this two- star programming.

Comment: I suspect that `Item` has subclasses, and that you're going to be surprised by *object slicing* soon. If it doesn't, there's no point in having an array of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

In the loop `i < cap, i++;`, you will first check if `i` is in bounds,  and then increase it by one before the loop body executes.  Thus if `i=cap-1` the check will pass, `i` will become `cap` and you're out of bounds.
Instead write `(size_t i = from; i < cap;i++)`, so that the increment of `i` is executed after the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

A see several problems with your code:

- In `Inventory::expand()`, since you are working with an array of pointers (why not an array of objects?), there is no need to make clones of the existing `Item` objects to the new array, just copy the existing pointers as-is. You are just expanding the array to fit more pointers, so the clones are wasted overhead.  Not a fatal issue, but it is something you should be aware of.
- In both `Inventory::initialize()` and `Inventory::expand()`, your loops are setup incorrectly.  You are performing the `i++` in the wrong place.  Given this definition of a loop:

  `for ( <init-statement> <condition> ; <iteration_expression> )`

  You are performing the `i++` as part of the `<condition>`, not the `<iteration_expression>`.  A simply typo caused by you using the [`comma operator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) instead of `;`, but an important typo nonetheless.
- `Inventory` is violating the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), by not implementing copy/move constructors and copy.move assignment operators.

With that said, try this instead:

```cpp
class Inventory
{
private:
    size_t cap;
    size_t nrOfItems;
    Item **itemArr;

    void expand();
    
public:
    Inventory();
    Inventory(const Inventory &src);
    Inventory(Inventory &&src);
    ~Inventory();

    Inventory& operator=(Inventory rhs);

    void addItem(const Item &item);
    void removeItem(size_t index);

    inline void debugPrint() const    
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nrOfItems; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << itemArr[i]->debugPrint() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

```cpp
Inventory::Inventory()
{
    cap = 10;
    nrOfItems = 0;
    itemArr = new Item*[cap]();
}

Inventory::Inventory(const Inventory &src)
{
    cap = src.cap;
    nrOfItems = src.nrOfItems;
    itemArr = new Item*[cap]();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nrOfItems; ++i)
    {
        itemArr[i] = new Item(*(src.itemArr[i]));
    }
}

Inventory::Inventory(Inventory &&src)
{
    cap = src.cap; src.cap = 0;
    nrOfItems = src.nrOfItems; src.nrOfItems = 0;
    itemArr = src.itemArr; src.itemArr = nullptr;
}

Inventory::~Inventory()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrOfItems; ++i)
    {
        delete itemArr[i];
    }
    delete[] itemArr;
}

Inventory& Inventory::operator=(Inventory rhs)
{
    Inventory temp(std::move(rhs));
    std::swap(cap, temp.cap);
    std::swap(nrOfItems, temp.nrOfItems);
    std::swap(itemArr, temp.itemArr);
    return *this;
}

void Inventory::expand()
{
    size_t newCap = cap * 2;
    Item **tempArr = new Item*[newCap]();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrOfItems; ++i)
    {
        tempArr[i] = itemArr[i];
    }

    delete[] itemArr;

    itemArr = tempArr;
    cap = newCap;
}

void Inventory::addItem(const Item& item)
{
    if (nrOfItems >= cap)
    {
        expand();
    }

    itemArr[nrOfItems] = new Item(item);
    ++nrOfItems;
}

void Inventory::removeItem(size_t index)
{
    if (index < nrOfItems)
    {
        Item *item = itemArr[index];

        for(size_t i = index + 1; i < nrOfItems; ++i)
        {
            itemArr[i-1] = itemArr[i];
        }

        --nrOfItems;
        itemArr[nrOfItems] = nullptr;

        delete item;
    }
}
```

---

That being said, you really should be using `std::vector` instead, let it handle these details for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Inventory
{
private:
    std::vector<Item> itemVec;
    
public:
    Inventory();

    void addItem(const Item &item);
    void removeItem(size_t index);

    inline void debugPrint() const    
    {
        for (Item &item : items)
        {
            std::cout << item.debugPrint() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

```cpp
Inventory::Inventory()
{
    itemVec.reserve(10);
}

void Inventory::addItem(const Item& item)
{
    itemVec.emplace_back(item);
}

void Inventory::removeItem(size_t index)
{
    if (index < itemVec.size())
    {
        itemVec.erase(itemVec.begin() + index);
    }
}
```

See how much simpler that is? :)